IBM MQ 1 way ssl minimum setup
I was trying to enable a self signed TLS from MQ docker. I followed the steps below to generate the mq keystore and client truststore.
runmqakm -keydb -create -db key.kdb -pw changeit -stash
runmqakm -cert  -create -db key.kdb -dn "cn=mqtest,o=mq,c=us" -pw changeit -label ibmwebspheremqqm -size 2048 -expire 3650
runmqakm -cert -list all -db key.kdb -stashed
runmqakm -cert -details -db key.kdb -stashed -label ibmwebspheremqqm
runmqakm -cert -extract -db key.kdb -stashed -label ibmwebspheremqqm -target QM1.cert
keytool -keystore clientkey.jks -storetype jks -importcert -file QM1.cert -alias server-certificate -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -noprompt

After creating the above keystore, i started modifying the queue manager and channel for 1 way tls connection. I am not able to connect to ueue after the above changes.
runmqsc QM1
ALTER QMGR SSLKEYR('/var/mqm/qmgrs/QM1/ssl/key') CERTLABL('ibmwebspheremqqm')
ALTER CHANNEL('DEV.APP.SVRCONN') CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) SSLCIPH(ANY_TLS12_OR_HIGHER) SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL) 
REFRESH SECURITY(*) TYPE(SSL)
EXIT

Can you point me , what i am doing wrong?

What error do you get in the client and qmgr AMQERR01.LOG files.

Below mqsc script worked for me for 1-way tls setup.
DISPLAY CHANNEL(DEV.APP.SVRCONN)
ALTER CHANNEL(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) SSLCIPH(ANY_TLS12) SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL) CERTLABL('')
REFRESH SECURITY(*) TYPE(SSL)
DISPLAY CHANNEL(DEV.APP.SVRCONN)
EXIT


You may be creating the wrong type of keystore. There is a -type cms option that I believe should be used with the -keydb -create command.
runmqakm documentation

Hi @Attila, the cms keystore type is default. If we do not add it or want a P12 file, it will create a cms type.

Also runmqakm uses GSKit to create the keystore and the queue manager also uses GSKit so it should be impossible to create a keystore with runmqakm that a queue manager cannot understand.

HI All,
If i am generating the server certificate as below:
cd /var/mqm/qmgrs/QM1/ssl/
runmqakm -keydb -create -db key.kdb -pw changeit -type cms -stash
runmqakm -cert  -create -db key.kdb -dn "cn=mqserver,o=mq,c=us" -pw changeit -label ibmwebspheremqqm1 -size 2048 -expire 3650
runmqakm -cert -list all -db key.kdb -stashed
runmqakm -cert -extract -db key.kdb -stashed -label ibmwebspheremqqm1 -target qm1server.cert
mv qm1server.cert /data/informatica/temp/mqcerts/
#mv clientkey.jks /data/informatica/temp/mqcerts/
ls /var/mqm/qmgrs/QM1/ssl/
chown mqm:mqm *
chmod 600 *```

and the client certificate as below:
runmqakm -keydb -create -db client.kdb -pw changeit -type cms -stash
runmqakm -cert  -create -db client.kdb -dn "cn=mqclient,o=mq,c=us" -pw changeit -label ibmwebspheremqapp -size 2048 -expire 3650
runmqakm -cert -extract -db client.kdb -stashed -label ibmwebspheremqapp -target appclient.cert

I am able to connect only when i set the SSLCAUTH to OPTIONAL. I am trying just 1 way ssl . What should be the right value of SSLCAUTH for that?

I can see that in the AMQERR01.LOG:
AMQ9637E: During handshake, the remote partner sent no certificate.
Does it mean that no certificate validation happened here?
